How to clear a cell value without using the delete or backspace keyboard keys?
How to clear a Google Sheets cell value in B2 when B1 value is entered, and vice versa?
I have tried this formula: =IF(B1<>"",clean(B2)).

Open Your Google Sheet:
Open the Google Sheet where you want to implement this functionality.
Go to the Script Editor:
Click on Extensions in the menu bar, then click on Apps Script. This will open the Google Apps Script editor.
Clear Existing Code:
If there's any existing code, delete it.
Paste the Provided Script:
Copy the provided script and paste it into the script editor.
Save the Script:
Click on File in the menu bar, then click on Save.
Test the Script:
You can now test the script. Edit either cell B1 or B2 in your Google Sheet. If you enter a value into one cell, the other cell should automatically clear its content.
Authorize the Script (If Prompted):
The first time you run a script in a Google Sheet, it may prompt you to authorize the script. Follow the on-screen instructions to do so. This is necessary for the script to be able to make changes to your sheet.
Close the Script Editor:
Once you've saved and tested the script successfully, you can close the script editor.
Done!:
The script will now run automatically whenever you edit cell B1 or B2 in your Google Sheet, clearing the content of the other cell when a value is entered.
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var cell = range.getA1Notation();
  
  // Check if the edited cell is B1 or B2
  if (cell === 'B1' || cell === 'B2') {
    // Clear the other cell if the edited cell is B1 or B2
    var otherCell = (cell === 'B1') ? 'B2' : 'B1';
    if (e.value !== '') {
      sheet.getRange(otherCell).clearContent();
    }
  }
}


This can't be done in Google Sheets by using formulas but can be done by using Google Apps Script.
It uses Javascript as progarming language and includes services and triggers.
You might use on edit or on change triggers.
One easy way is to create a script from Google Sheets. For details start by trading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
